# Visual Studio throws output:RuntimeBinderException dereferencing ViewBag.property on MVC 5 Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 5` with `Entity Framework 6`

Today I updated some components using NuGet, (e.g. `MVC 5.2.0.0` updated to `MVC 5.2.2.0`), also updated `EF6` to new version along with other components.

But now the **Visual Studio output window always displays**:

> A first chance exception of type
>
> 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.CSharp.dll

Then I open the exception panel and select **Common Language Runtime Exception** (on Visual Studio 2013: press Ctrl+Alt+E) then I find the source from my Razor page for every **ViewBag**:

```
ViewBag.Title = Resource.ApplicationName;
```

My project razor page uses all the ViewBag properties, so sometimes I can see a lot of `RuntimeBinderException` occurrences. **It only outputs--never triggers anything--until I checked Common Language Runtime Exception on Visual Studio**

So,  what's going on?  Is there anyway to hide it? Why it display now? Why did it not display before?